# Plotly: How to create custom hover Labels for Plotly 3D Scatter figures?

Tags: python, dataframe, 3d, plotly

I'm using plotly to graph the similarities between movies based on their plot using PCA. Since this is just a visual representation I'm trying to produce, I don't really care about seeing the PCA values for each data point. I just want to see the title of the film, and maybe some other features like genre and rating. The x,y,z values are just making the graph look messy.

Below is the actual code used, although I don't have the movie_similarities function, it does just return a dataframe `return pd.DataFrame({'pca_0':np.array([0,1,2,3]), 'pca_1':np.array([0,1,2,3]),'pca_2':np.array([0,1,2,3]),'Title':np.array(['Fight Club','Mission: Impossible','Harry Potter'])})`

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as pyo
pyo.init_notebook_mode()


    df = pd.DataFrame({'pca_0':np.array([0,1,2,3]), 'pca_1':np.array([0,1,2,3]),'pca_2':np.array([0,1,2,3]),'Title':np.array(['Fight Club','Mission: Impossible','Harry Potter'])})`
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(
        x=df.pca_0, # ie [0, 1, 2, 3]
        y=df.pca_1, # ie [0, 1, 2, 3]
        z=df.pca_2, # ie [0, 1, 2, 3]
        hovertext = df.Title, # ie ['Fight Club','Mission: Impossible','Harry Potter']
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            size=8,
            opacity=0.8
        )
    )])

    fig.show()
```

Comment: A data sample would be nice!

Comment: There's one in the question

Comment: A data sample ***to make your code snippet reproducible*** would be nice.  As in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As it now stands, your snippet raises the error `NameError: name 'data' is not defined`.

Comment: I'm not near a pc right now to test but hopefully the above will work

Comment: Probably. I'll take a look.

Comment: Your current data sample would produce a 3D scatter plot with *one* marker since the coordinates would be identical for all titles. I'll use other data in a suggestion that will pop up in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing on...

> I don't really care about seeing the PCA values for each data point. I
>   just want to see the title of the film

... the right combination of `hovertemplate='<b>%{text}</b>'` and `text` should do the trick`:

[image]

**Complete code with data sample:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as pyo
import pandas as pd
pyo.init_notebook_mode()


df = pd.DataFrame({'pca_0':np.array([4,1,2,3]),
                   'pca_1':np.array([9,11,12,13]),
                   'pca_2':np.array([0,5,1,8]),
                   'Title':np.array(['Fight Club','Mission: Impossible','Harry Potter', 'Star Wars'])})
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(
    x=df.pca_0, # ie [0, 1, 2, 3]
    y=df.pca_1, # ie [0, 1, 2, 3]
    z=df.pca_2, # ie [0, 1, 2, 3]
    hovertemplate='<b>%{text}</b><extra></extra>',
    text = [title for title in df.Title],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=8,
        opacity=0.8
    )
)])

fig.show()
```

Comment: Great thanks for this. Looks like the text variable can take html formatting so something like `df.Title + '<br> Score: ' + df.Score.astype(str)` can be used to add more than one column in the dataframe. Also `text` looks like it can take a series of the same length as the data so `df.Title` can be used rather than a list comprehension.